# How does one construct the concrete Heisenberg vertex operator algebra for the case of 3d Heisenberg group and associated lie algebra?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, operator-algebras, conformal-field-theory, heisenberg-group

It seems I am feeling my way down a blind alley. I'm trying to understand this Heisenberg vertex operator in the concrete case of 3 dimensional Heisenberg group.

It would seem that generally vertex algebra can be defined this way for a polynomial ring.

Given say $V = \mathbb{C}[x_{-1}, x_{-2}, . . . .]$, a vacuum,a translation and vertex operation can be defined.

A simple form for the translation and vertex operation are the below:

```
      data
```

$V = \mathbb{C}[x_{-1}, x_{-2}, . . . .]$

Let a vacuum exist, $\mathbb{1}$

$T(x_{-n}) =(-n) . x_{-n -1}$

$Y(x,z)$ = ${\Sigma}_n x_n z^{-n -1}$

Then

$a, b \in V $, $a_n b =  Y(a,z)b$

This seems to be a simple form of this idea.

If anything I've said above is true, then maybe I can ask my question.

In my own notation (which seems to be natural as I have checked and it is close to what others are using), I am referring to the VOA as  (V, 1, T, Y) following a definition I stitched up based on the above.

That is what are V, 1, T, and Y for the Heisenberg vertex operator algebra in the simplest possible form?

The 3-dimensional Heisenberg Lie algebra seems to be formed from its have 3 basis elements.

$X = \pmatrix{ 0 &1&0 \\
           0 &0&0 \\
           0&0&0}$
$Y = \pmatrix{ 0 &0&0 \\
           0 &0&1 \\
           0 &0&0}$
$Z = \pmatrix{ 0 &0&1 \\
           0 &0&0 \\
           0&0&0}$

Page 18 through 20 of [this](https://researchers.ms.unimelb.edu.au/%7Edridout@unimelb/students/Tan.MScThesis.pdf) reference construct the vertex operator algebra but it is a bit too abstract and I don't believe I have understood it because I am having trouble translating it.

Also, see page 13 of [this](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/%7Ejoyce/VertexAlgebras2021/VA3+4.pdf)

My understanding of the matter is something like this:

Take h, the lie algebra . .  Look at the basis and add $h_c$ a central term then this is supposed to be your V (or H in some notation ). Then the 'data' proceed from here.

How does one construct the concrete Heisenberg vertex operator algebra for the case of 3d Heisenberg group and associated lie algebra?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138286/discussion-on-question-by-kevin-njokom-how-does-one-construct-the-concrete-heise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I know this question is old like the other I answered, just trying to breath life to vertex algebras on MSE)

This construction actually isn't possible for the 3D Heisenberg Lie algebra, the reason being that if $\text{dim}V$ is finite, then the vertex algebra structure is necessarily a trivial one (e.g. all fields commute and V has the structure of a commutative associative algebra with the vacuum as its identity element); see e.g. Exercises 2.12-13 in the excellent http://library.msri.org/books/Book57/files/40mason.pdf or the related Theorem 5.1.4 in *Moonshine Beyond the Monster* by Terry Gannon. Consequently, any nontrivial vertex algebra will have an infinite-dimensional underlying vector space.

If you have experience with abstract algebra then looking at chapter 1 of *Vertex Operator Algebras and the Monster* by Frenkel, Lepowsky, and Meurman might help since they introduce algebras (including Lie algebras), modules of algebras, induced modules, and the universal enveloping algebra of a Lie algebra, which are a large part of the machinery used to construct these examples in the more abstract way. Unfortunately I don't think there is any example more concrete than the Heisenberg algebra with $V=\mathbb{C}[[x_{-1},x_{-2},...]]$ and the data you described.